# Center form input but not label

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, django-templates

What I have:

[image: have]

What I want:

[image: want]

I would like to have the input centered on the page and have the label sit to the left of it using bootstrap 4 if possible. I think I might need to offset or pull the columns, but it seems justify-content center ignores any pull or offset class.

HTML (Django):

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}

    <div class="row my-4 justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-2  float-right text-right">
            {{ field.label }}
        </div>

        <div class="col-4  float-left"> 
            <div class="accountFieldWrapper">
                {{ field|add_class:"form-control w-100" }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}

    <div class="row my-4 justify-content-center">
        <button class="primaryAction btn btn-dark" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
    </div>

    <div class="row my-4 justify-content-center">
        <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
    </div>


</form>
```

Comment: You posted the server side code above but in this case (since it's a frontend issue) you should provide the rendered source with the elements rendered, basically the source code the browser gets.

Comment: My question is about how to use bootstrap for my use case, it's not actually an issue or bug. I don't think there's any helpful context in the rendered html.